# How to set codeview by default when Angular Summernote is loaded

Tags: angularjs, summernote

How to configure Angular Summernote to set HTML codeview by default. 
Here is my settings on scope

```
$scope.options = {
        height: 200,
        focus: true,
        toolbar: [
            ['view', ['codeview']]
        ]
};
```

But I have to click codeview button, which I want it active by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly about angular-summernote. If you can access element with jquery, You can change mode with API.

```
$('.summernote').summernote(); // initailize summernote
$('.summernote').summernote('codeview.toggle'); // to codeview
```

For more codeview API...
https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/develop/src/js/base/module/Codeview.js#L20

Comment: This API was provided after v0.7.0. Could you check your version?